# UIButton can't be touched while animated with UIView animateWithDuration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I have the following code:

```cpp
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect r = [btn frame];
                     r.origin.y -= 40;
                     [btn setFrame: r];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL done){
                     if(done){
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                                               delay:1
                                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                                          animations:^{
                                              CGRect r = [btn frame];
                                              r.origin.y += 40;
                                              [btn setFrame: r];
                                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL done){if(done) zombiePopping = 0; }];
                     }

                 }];
```

The problem is, it seems the button doesnt respond to touches while being animated even though i'm using `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowInteraction`, which is a bit weird to me.

Maybe this most be done with Core Animation to work? and if so, how would i go about that?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The touchable part of the button will not coincide with the button's visible frame when it is being animated.

Internally, the button's frame will be set to the final value from your animation. You should find that you can tap in this area, and it would work.

To hit a moving button, you need to do hit testing on the button's `.layer.presentationLayer` property (need to import the QuartzCore framework to do this). This would typically be done in touch handling methods in your view controller.

I am happy to expand on this answer if you need more.

Here is how you would respond to a touch event by hit testing presentation layers. This code is in the view controller subclass that is managing your buttons. When I did this I was interested in the initial touch rather than the touch ending (which is typically when a tap would register) but the principle is the same.

Remember to import the QuartzCore framework and add it to your project.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    for (UIButton *button in self.buttonsOutletCollection)
    {
        if ([button.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:touchLocation])
        {
            // This button was hit whilst moving - do something with it here
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your other option is to move the buttons in very small increments on a repeating timer, as you would in a game updating loop. Hit tests on 8 buttons is pretty trivial, if they are in an array.

Comment: Can you give me some code examples? im not sure exactly what are my options, thanks again :)

Comment: The buttons are in an array (IBOutletCollection)

Comment: I've updated the answer. I don't have a sample for the timer option, I've only done it this way.

Comment: @jrturton Tks Tks... +10.. I spent a day in the dark... before that

Comment: Can anyone explain where would I call this method?
(NSSet *)touches is not clear to me. I can't figure out what is this

Comment: @Stebra You don't call this method. UIKit calls it for you, on your view controller.

Comment: what is buttonsOutletCollection in above code?? please explain me

Comment: @mohitpopat it's an outlet to an IBOutletCollection, which is an array of items that you can link up in interface builder.

Comment: any chance you can rewrite this in swift

Comment: @msweet168 feel free to try it yourself and update the answer

Comment: Havent figured it out

Answer (score 62):

## Swift 5

In my case, when I set `button.alpha = 0`, the button interaction stops working, no matter if I setup **`UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction`** as an option.

### Reason

Whenever you define the animation or not, **the view's property is applying to view's layer immediately**. Because of this, when you set the `view.alpha=0`, you hide the `view` completely.

### Solution

Easy, just reduce `alpha=0.1` (or even `0.05`)

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2,
                       delay: 0,
                       options: [.allowUserInteraction, .overrideInheritedOptions, .curveEaseOut, .repeat, .autoreverse],
                       animations: {
                           self.button.layer.opacity = 0.01 // 0.0 will make the button unavailable to touch
        })
```

Comment: this small hack need 100 thumbs up. 1 sec change and everything works. Awesome

Comment: Definitely the best answer.

Comment: Best answer ever.

Comment: Swift Code         UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0,
                       delay: 0,
                       options:[UIViewAnimationOptions.repeat, UIViewAnimationOptions.allowUserInteraction],
                       animations:
                        {
                            button.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
                        },
                       completion:nil);

Comment: Also worth looking into, though I haven't tested, you might be able to animate the view.layer.opacity to 0.0 and still keep touches available, if you do need to fade ALL the way out for some reason.

Comment: OMG!!? Why?? Why when I have **delayed** animation which have alpha=0 the interaction DOESN'T WORK even before animation started?! Even if I set `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` option... which idiot comes to this so called "solution"

Answer (score 34):

The order of the options are matters, you have to place `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` first, then add other options.

In Swift 3 use: `options: [.allowUserInteraction]` within the `UIView`'s animation block.

Comment: Can you elaborate why the order supposed to be important? It's an `OptionSet` type which implies a bitmask, the order in which you provide each flag should not patter at all. I also don't see the justification of the up-votes, because there is no source provided that confirms your claim.

Comment: @DevAndArtist you can try it yourself, then you will know why I said that the order matters. Let me know if you have different result, or be nice, no one is paid for answering questions.

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved this using NSTimer:
First, execute start animation, then you should start a timer, this is the demo code:

```
-(void)fun···
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut |  UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect r = [btn frame];
                     r.origin.y -= 40;
                     [btn setFrame: r];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL done){}];

    then , you should start an timer,example:
    //start timer
   if (timer != nil)
   {
       [timer invalidate];
       timer = nil;
   }
   [self performSelector:@selector(closeButton) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}


- (void)closeButton
{
    if (timer != nil)
    {
        return;
    }

    //start timer
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.5f target:self selector:@selector(timerEvent) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

- (void)timerEvent
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                                               delay:1
                                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                                          animations:^{
                                              CGRect r = [btn frame];
                                              r.origin.y += 40;
                                              [btn setFrame: r];
                                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL done){if(done) zombiePopping = 0; }];
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same answer in Swift (2.0), for the lazy. Replace with a loop and outlet collection if necessary:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    let touchLocation = touch!.locationInView(self.view)
    if self.button.layer.presentationLayer()!.hitTest(touchLocation) != nil {
        action() // Your action, preferably the original button action.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0** 
Create a superview on top in viewdidload

```
let superView = UIView(frame: view.frame)
    superView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    superView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    superView.alpha = 0.1
    view.addSubview(superView)
```

now implement touchesbagan like this

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    guard let touch = (touches as NSSet).anyObject() as? UITouch else {
        return
    }

    let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self.view)
    if btnone.layer.presentation()?.hitTest(touchLocation) != nil {
        print("1") // Do stuff for button 
    }
    if btntwo.layer.presentation()?.hitTest(touchLocation) != nil {
        print("2") // Do stuff
    }
    if btnthree.layer.presentation()?.hitTest(touchLocation) != nil {
        print(3) // Do stuff
    }
    if btnfour.layer.presentation()?.hitTest(touchLocation) != nil {
        print(4) // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a subclass of the UIButton the easiest way is by overriding the hitTest like

```
public override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        return self.layer.presentation()?.hitTest(self.convert(point, to: superview)).flatMap { _ in return self } ?? nil
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had 4 buttons on screen which should serve as navigation to left, righ, down and up. I used simple hack from @nahung89 answer and added completion to get full effect I needed. 
Here is the code:

1. Connected all buttons to Outlet collection in ViewController

   ```
   @IBOutlet var navigationButtons: [UIButton]!
   ```
2. Added this funcion in viewDidAppear:

   ```
       navigationButtons.forEach { button in
           UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
                                   delay: 5,
                                   options: [.curveLinear, .allowUserInteraction],
                                   animations: {
                                       button.alpha = 0.1
           }) { _ in button.alpha = 0 }
       }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift version:**
'999' is tag value used to identify the target view.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let touchLocation = (touch?.locationInView(self.rootView))!

        for view in self.view.subviews {
            if let layer = view.layer.presentationLayer()?.hitTest(touchLocation) where view.tag == 999 {
                // Here view is the tapped view
                print(view)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

works like a charm

`override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if bounds.contains(point) && !hidden && userInteractionEnabled && enabled {
        return self
    }
    return super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event)
}`

Although [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31102406/2982854) answer is also correct