# UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction not working

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to detect a touch whilst my `UIImageView` is animating.
The touch detection works before the animation starts, and once it
stops, but not during.

I've tried adding `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction`, but it
seems to have no effect at all!

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    NSLog(@"tag=%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", touch]);
    if ([touch view] == itemCoke)
    {
        NSLog(@"Coke Touched");
    }

}

- (IBAction)removeItemButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Pushed");


    [UIView animateWithDuration:5 
                          delay:0.0         
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^
                             {
                                 itemCoke.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(itemCoke.transform, (M_PI*-0.5));
                                 itemCoke.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50);
                             }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){}];   
}
```

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason the interactions are not working is that essentially the `UIImageView` is not where it appears to be. Only the view's `CALayer`'s presentation layer is being animated around the screen. The view has already arrived at it's destination immediately. This makes interaction much harder. [You will likely find this answer helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8346178/927947)

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick

```
-(UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
if ([[self.layer presentationLayer] hitTest:point]) {
    return self;
}
return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];}
```

write it in your uiview

Comment: Be careful. If the user taps on the spot to which the view is animating, this will return a false positive (because while the `presentationLayer` hit test will fail, the `super` one will use the destination frame for hit test purposes.