# UIButton not responding when animating

Tags: objective-c

For some reason my UIButton won't respond to UIControlEvents while animating. Here's how I animate:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:[duration intValue]];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
// change parent UIView's frame
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

When it reaches the end, it will let me tap it... but not while it's animating. I am using UIControlEventTouchUpInside, by the way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should set the `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` animation option

easier done with block animations:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:[duration intValue] options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations^{
    //set parent UIView's frame
}];
```

Comment: according to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346100/uibutton-cant-be-touched-while-animated-with-uiview-animatewithduration) the touchable frame of the button isnt always aligned with the visible frame, so you may need to do some custom touch handling

Comment: +1, thanks it helped me for ios 4. as ios 5 & 6 doesnt need this method :)