# UISegmentedControl not responding within UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UIView` property named `viewToFade` that contains a `UISegmentedControl`.  When I animate the `UIView` (so it appears on tapping and gradually fades), the `UISegmentedControl` doesn't respond to touches.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
-(void)fadeView
{
self.viewToFade.alpha=1;
self.viewToFade.hidden=NO;

//When I comment the following lines out, everything is fine--the `UISegmentedControl` responds as it should.  
//But when I include them, the `UISegmentedControl` doesn't register changes/taps.

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay: 3.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{
                     self.viewToFade.alpha = 0.0;
                 }
                 completion:nil];
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

(In case it's relevant, I'll say that the `UIView` and the `UISegmentedControl` are both created in the xib file.)

**EDIT:** I figured out a way to deal with the problem, which was to rewrite the code as follows:

```
-(void)fadeView
{
self.viewToFade.alpha=1;
self.viewToFade.hidden=NO;
[self performSelector:@selector(disneyfy) withObject:nil afterDelay:(3)];
} 

-(void)disneyfy
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                 animations:^{
                     self.viewToFade.alpha = 0.0;
                 }];
}
```

Comment: This is unexpected to me. Not sure if it is relevant, but what OS version are you running it on?

Comment: Yes I met the same issue, parent-view's alpha **will change** if child-view's alpha changed, but child-view's alpha **won't change** if parent-view's alpha changed.

Comment: This question should help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8346100/937822

Comment: I guess I am misunderstanding, if viewToFade contains the segmented control, it will disappear when it's parent alpha = 0.0.  A view won't respond to touches when it's alpha=0.0 (or it's ancestors).  But it's also not visible to touch.  Am I mixed up on this?

Comment: @danh: The system considers the alpha to be 0 before the animation even starts. It does NOT gradually change the alpha. That is, after half the animation is done, the alpha is not 0.5. It will go from 1 to 0, no in-between values.

Answer (score 1):

I played around with this in a sample project and could duplicate your results - nothing I did even animating (in my case) a button itself rendered it immune to touches. However in my limited test I was able to see that it did respond to highlighting.

I just tested the following (using a UIBuutton, suppose the same thing will work for segmented control):

- add a transparent view over your button, and add a gesture recognizer to it, just before the animation
- have the actionMethod of the tap recognizer change the highlighting of the button on, then dispatch a block to turn it off in 100ms or so (you could get fancier if you actually intercept touches).
- in addition to changing the highlighting, send something like this to the control (again using a button) :

  ```
  [tapButton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  ```

It appears the control is responsive to such things during the animation.

Comment: Oooh, this looks great!  Unfortunately, I'm too much a newbie to know how to implement it--I don't understand blocks (I got the block code I used from the Apple documentation).  I did find a solution to my problem (original question edited), but I suspect it's far less elegant than this.

Comment: If its just blocks you are cannot deal with, you can use one of the 'performSelector' messages that has 'after' parameter. Otherwise, offer a bound of 50 pts to the person who codes this for you. You need to specify the number of segments, if they are momentary or selectable.