# UIView rotation and Subview (Button) touch

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have a `UIView` and on this `UIView` I have 8 buttons.  I need to rotate this `UIVIew` every time So I am using the code below:

```
CABasicAnimation *fullRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
fullRotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
fullRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
fullRotation.duration = 30;
fullRotation.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT;
[self.menuView.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];
```

It rotates my view properly, But I am unable to get touch on rotating buttons. Since the Parent view is rotating and the Buttons will also rotate, Touch isn't working.  Thanks

Comment: Checkout this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8346178/1228534

Answer (score 0):

Because you rotate layer. I think you can't do what you need, but try to use CGAffineTransform

```
CGAffineTransform transform //desired transform
[UIView animateWithDuration:time
                 animations:^{menuView.transform = transform;}];
```

and call it by timer.

Answer (score 0):

Normal view touches do not work correctly during an animation. Animation only makes the views look like they are moving. Their actual coordinates don't move.

If you want to support tapping on objects you will need to roll your own tap handling code at the superview level using the presentation layer's hitTest method.

I have a sample project on github that shows how to do that:

[iOS Core Animation demo](https://github.com/DuncanMC/iOS-CAAnimation-group-demo)