# Animation does not allow button to be clickable

Tags: ios

I have implemented a flashing effect on microphone button while it is recording. Now it does not allow me to click to stop. I could not able to figure out the root of the problem

-

```
 (IBAction)microButton:(id)sender {

    if(counter%2==0)
    {
        if (!recorder.recording) {

            AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
            [session setActive:YES error:nil];
            [micImage setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ico_mic_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                                  delay:0.0
                                options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                             animations:^{
                                 self.micImage.alpha = 0.0f;
                             }
                             completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             }];

            // Start recording
            [recorder record];
        }
        counter=counter+1;

    }
    else{
        [recorder stop];

        AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [audioSession setActive:NO error:nil];
            counter=counter+1;
        [micImage setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ico_mic.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.micImage.alpha = 1.0f;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                         animations:^{
                             self.micImage.alpha = 1.0f;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         }];
    }
}
```

Comment: This Stack Overflow answer might help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8346178/1524132

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you set the `alpha` to 0, iOS thinks you want the view to be hidden, and hence disables touch events for it.  The easiest way to avoid the problem will be to set `alpha` to a low value (there appears to be a threshold, some say 0.1 is OK, but try a few values).  The image will not quite disappear (which is probably OK in your case, since it is oscillating) but the touches will be recognised.