# UITapGestureRecongnizer during animation failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, animation, uigesturerecognizer

I am using the following code to generate an image which is touchable.

I read some posts here saying `UIButton` cannot be used during animation so I changed to use tap gesture. I have also added the `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` in option. But I still cannot make it work. May I know the reason and any solution?

```
hit1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(539,227,50,50)];
hit1.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"roles.png"];

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hitenermy:)];
[hit1 addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[hit1 setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
[hit1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
hit1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;


[self.view addSubview:hit1];
[hit1 addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
UIViewAnimationOptions options = UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction;

[UIView animateWithDuration:15.0
                      delay:1.0
                    options:options
                 animations:^{
                     hit1.center = CGPointMake(hit1.center.x-210, hit1.center.y-60);

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                 }];
```

Comment: what is happening when u tap the imageView?

Comment: You have to add layer animation & then you can use TapGestureRecognizer to detect tap

Comment: When the view starts, the button appear and started moving. I set the duration to 15sec. But at the first 10sec, there is not response when i touch it. At the end of the animation around last 5 sec, the image responded.

Comment: @Clarence why you set twice addGestureRecognizer and setUserInteractionEnabled?

Comment: can u show code for hitenermy: method

Comment: @Gagan_iOS What code should i added to make layer animation?

Comment: @DheerajSingh -(void)hitenermy:(UIButton*)sender{
    for (LDProgressView *progressView2 in self.progressViews2) {
        float fullhp =progressView2.progress;
        float hitone = 0.31;
        progressView2.progress= fullhp-hitone;
  
    }
}

Comment: Instead of adding animation on object you can add animation on object's layers. Now add tap gesture on your object. This should work.
For getting layer, you can simply write: YoursObject.Layer
For layer animation you can serach over Apple or Stackoverflow.

Comment: Why you are applying delay in your animation?In animate with duration, you are specifying value 1.0????? [UIView animateWithDuration:15.0
                      delay:1.0
                    options:options
                 animations:^{
                     hit1.center = CGPointMake(hit1.center.x-210, hit1.center.y-60);

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                 }];

Comment: Try after changing delay from 1 to 0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` to get touch event.
I have shown for a single imageView but if multiple imageView are present then u can use tag to differentiate them.

you can get more from :[UIButton can't be touched while animated with UIView animateWithDuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346100/uibutton-cant-be-touched-while-animated-with-uiview-animatewithduration)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        hit1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(539,227,50,50)];
        hit1.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"roles.png"];

        [self.view addSubview:hit1];

        UIViewAnimationOptions options = UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:15.0
                              delay:1.0
                            options:options
                         animations:^{
                              hit1.center = CGPointMake(hit1.center.x-210, hit1.center.y-60);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         }];
    }



     - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
        {
            UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
            CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
            for (UIImageView *imageView in self.view.subviews)
            {
                if ([imageView.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:touchLocation])
                {
                    NSLog(@"Clicked");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, but when i use this code i found another problem. No matter where i touch, any location of the screen, it still detecting the touch. Not just the image. Why this happens?? Thanks

Comment: it is because the touch event is for your whole view.

Comment: Is it possible to specifically event for the image view?

Comment: i don't think it would be possible ,but u can use  UIView *hitView = [self hitTest:touchLocation withEvent:event]; if([hitView == yourimageview]) then perform actions on your touch on imageview