# Buttons are not working while setting alpha of a view having buttons?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, stack-overflow, alpha

```
- (void)animateView:(UIView *)animatedView afterDelay:(float)delay {
    NSLog(@"delay is here which i am looking for %f",del);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:9 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^ {
                         animatedView.alpha = 0.2f;

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:9 animations:^ {
                             animatedView.alpha = 0.7;
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             [self animateView:animatedView afterDelay:9 ];
                         }];
                     }];
```

Comment: add some more informaton about your issue and flow about.

Comment: See this: [Buttons not working during animation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8346178/4078527)