# UILabel does not handle gesture while being animated

Tags: swift, uilabel, uipangesturerecognizer, uianimation

I have an `UILabel` object which is in a continuous animation using a `UIView.animate()` option. This is working as expected.

I then added a pan gesture (`UIPanGestureRecognizer`) to this object. However, it does not respond to any pan action while animating. The associated action method is not even invoked based on the debugging that I did. As soon as I disabled its animation, the action method gets triggered when panned and the label handles the gesture correctly. I am wondering if I should suspend its animation when the relevant gesture is initiated. The issue is the action method is not being invoked at all, so I am unsure how to achieve that.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you can find this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346100/uibutton-cant-be-touched-while-animated-with-uiview-animatewithduration

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very quick reply! I don't know how my searches failed to find that. I shall add an answer here based on your link.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Rishabh, I addressed this issue based on the discussion in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346100/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346100/uibutton-cant-be-touched-while-animated-with-uiview-animatewithduration). I added `.allowUserInteraction` as options to the `animate` method as shown below:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 10.0, delay: 0.0, options: [ .allowUserInteraction, .curveLinear ], animations: {
...
})
```

And now the label is able to animate and still responds to pan!